# WTForm: FieldList with SelectField, how do I render?

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I have this order form that allows my users to create an order. An order consists of multiple tuples of `(producetype, quantity)`. Producetype should be rendered in a `<select>` form while quantity can just be an input. The choices of producetype should be dynamically added because that could change. Currently, I've written this in bare html

[image]

I would like to use WTForm for this because WTForm really simplifies my code. However, I am unable to do so:

Code:

```
class OrderEntryForm(Form):
  quantity = IntegerField('Quantity',
                          [validators.Required(), validators.NumberRange(min=1)])
  # we will be dynamically adding choices
  producetype = SelectField('Produce',
                            [validators.Required()],
                            choices=[])

class OrderForm(Form):
  name = TextField('Crop', [validators.Length(min=3, max=60)])
  due_date = DateField('Due Date', [validators.required()])
  order_entries = FieldList(FormField(OrderEntryForm))
```

I have the following questions:

1. How can I dynamically add choices to the `order_entries` field of the OrderForm?
2. If I have an order, `order = { name:hello, due_date:2014-06-18, order_entries:[ {producetype_id: 1, quantity: 2}, {producetype_id: 3, quantity: 4}] }`, how can populate my `OrderForm` with the right `OrderEntryForm` values?

Answer (score 9):

> How can I dynamically add choices to the order_entries field of the OrderForm

This depends on what you mean

If you mean you want to add lines items to the form after render. You have to use DOM manipulation to add these on the client side. *WTForms* has a naming convention for addressing indices on form fields. Its just `name="<form-field-name>-<index>"`. If you add a name using javascript that follows this convention *WTForms* will know how to handle it on the backend.

If you mean you want to have a dynamic choice list then you can just iterate over the `FieldList` in the form after its instantiated. You can assign `choices` any iterable of 2-tuples. In the example below I am assigning them directly but they could just as easily have been retrieved from storage.

```
order_form = OrderForm()
for sub_form in order_form.order_entries:
    sub_form.producetype.choices = [('2', 'apples'), ('2', 'oranges')]
```

> how can populate my OrderForm with the right OrderEntryForm values?

You can just bind objects directly to the form using the `obj` keyword argument. *WTForms* is smart enough to dynamically build the form from the object's attributes.

```
from wtforms import Form, IntegerField, SelectField, TextField, FieldList, FormField
from wtforms import validators
from collections import namedtuple

OrderEntry = namedtuple('OrderEntry', ['quantity', 'producetype'])
Order = namedtuple('Order', ['name', 'order_entries'])

class OrderEntryForm(Form):
  quantity = IntegerField('Quantity',
                          [validators.Required(), validators.NumberRange(min=1)])
  # we will be dynamically adding choices
  producetype = SelectField('Produce',
                            [validators.Required()],
                            choices=[
                                (1, 'carrots'),
                                (2, 'turnips'),
                            ])

class OrderForm(Form):
  name = TextField('Crop', [validators.Length(min=3, max=60)])
  order_entries = FieldList(FormField(OrderEntryForm))

# Test Print of just the OrderEntryForm
o_form = OrderEntryForm()
print o_form.producetype()

# Create a test order
order_entry_1 = OrderEntry(4, 1)
order_entry_2 = OrderEntry(2, 2)

order = Order('My First Order', [order_entry_1, order_entry_2])

order_form = OrderForm(obj=order)

print order_form.name
print order_form.order_entries
```

The above example creates a sample `Order` and supplies it to the `obj` keyword. On render this will generate the following(unstyled):

[image]

Comment: This was very helpful. Thank you. However, I have another problem directly related to your solution. Would you be kind enough to take a look as well? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24324161/wtform-how-do-i-tell-form-to-use-a-custom-method-for-one-particular-attribute

Comment: how do you style this to get rid of Order Entries-0 etc?

Comment: you can add styles inline with `To render a field, simply call it, providing any values the widget expects as keyword arguments. Usually the keyword arguments are used for extra HTML attributes.` or you can add stylesheets in the document itself just like you normally would when working with html/css.

Answer (score 7):

For anyone else stumped by `SelectField`s + `FieldList`s, this is how I implemented a `FieldList` with `SelectField`s (inspired by [nsfyn55's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24316196/7781935)). This approach dynamically renders an arbitrary number of SelectFields to the `/home` route based on JSON data.

**The route** (routes.py):

```py
@app.route('/home', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def home():
    custom_metadata = data

    select_metadata_form_list = SelectFormList()
    select_metadata_form_list.select_entries = get_select_entries()

    context = {
        "select_metadata_form_list": select_metadata_form_list,
    }

    return render_template('home.html', **context)
```

**The forms** (forms.py):

```py
class SelectForm(FlaskForm):
    select = SelectField("Placeholder", choices=[])


class SelectFormList(FlaskForm):
    select_entries = FieldList(FormField(SelectForm))
```

**The template** (`home.html`):

```html
{% for select_form in select_metadata_form_list.select_entries %}
    {{select_form.select.label}}: {{ select_form.select}}
{% endfor %}
```

**Helper methods** (app.py):

```py
def get_select_entries():
    """
    Converts custom metadata to a forms.SelectForm(), which can then be
    used by SelectFormlist() to dynamically render select items.

    :return: <forms.SelectForm object>
    """
    select_data = get_select_data_from_custom_metadata()

    select_data_labeled = get_labled_select_data(select_data=select_data)

    all_select_items = []
    for select_dict in select_data_labeled:
        for k, v in select_dict.items():
            select_id = uuid.uuid1()   # allows for multiple selects
            select_entry = SelectForm()
            select_entry.select.label = k
            select_entry.id = select_id
            select_entry.select.choices = v
            all_select_items.append(select_entry)

    return all_select_items
```

```py
def get_select_data_from_custom_metadata():
    """
    [
    {"Seniority": ["Intern", "Associate", "Senior"]}
    ]
    :return: List of dictionaries containing key and list of select values
    """
    type = "select"
    select_data = []
    custom_metadata = get_custom_metadata()

    for field in custom_metadata["fields"]:
        if field["type"] == type:
            select_data.append({field["key"]: field["data_list"]})

    return select_data
```

**The 'data'** (custom_metadata.json):

```json
{
  "fields": [
    {
      "type": "text",
      "key": "Position"
    },

    {
      "type": "select",
      "key": "Seniority",
      "data_list": ["Intern", "Associate", "Senior", "Executive"]
    },
    {
      "type": "select",
      "key": "Company",
      "data_list": ["Ford", "Chevy", "Toyota"]
    },
    {
      "type": "select",
      "key": "Team",
      "data_list": ["Bucks", "Raptors", "Thunder"]
    }
  ]
}
```

**The result**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add a `SubmitField` to your to `OrderForm`:

```
submit_something = SubmitField((u'Add something'))
```

and then call it from your view, and use the `append_entry` method of `FieldList`:

```
if form.submit_something.data:
         form.order_entries.append_entry()
         return render_template('yourtemplate.html', form=form)
```

Hope that helps !