# WTForm: how do I tell Form to use a custom method for one particular attribute?

Tags: python, wtforms

I have the following definitions:

```
class ProduceType(ndb.Model):
  crop = ndb.StringProperty()
  variety = ndb.StringProperty()

class OrderEntry(ndb.Model):
  producetype = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=ProduceType, required=True)
  quantity = ndb.IntegerProperty(required=True)
```

I created the following WTForm:

```
class OrderEntryForm(Form):
  quantity = IntegerField('Quantity',
                          [validators.Required(), validators.NumberRange(min=1)])
  # we will be dynamically adding choices
  producetype = SelectField('Produce',
                            [validators.Required()],
                            choices=[])
```

This is what I am doing in my tests:

```
def setUp(self):
  self.pt1 = ProduceType(crop='Choi', variety='Bok')
  self.pt2 = ProduceType(crop='Cress', variety='True')
  self.pt1.put()
  self.pt2.put()

def test_order_entry(self):
  oe = OrderEntry(producetype=self.pt1.key, quantity=20)
  oef = OrderEntryForm(obj=oe)
  oef.producetype.choices = [
      (self.pt1.key.id(), self.pt1.name()),
      (self.pt2.key.id(), self.pt2.name())
  ]
  print oef.producetype
```

And this is what's being printed:

```
<select id="producetype" name="producetype"><option value="1">Choi - Bok</option><option value="2">Cress - True</option></select>
```

**Problem:**
I am trying to render the form for my users to edit.

So if an OrderEntry in my database looks likes:

```
order_entry = { producetype: self.pt1.key, quantity: 5 }
```

I would expect WTForms to be rendering something like:

```
<select id="producetype" name="producetype">
  <option value="1" selected>Choi - Bok</option>
  <option value="2">Cress - True</option>
</select>
```

However, right now I cannot get WTForm to render the **selected** properly. The select being rendered is currently empty.

How do I get WTForm to render **selected** correctly?

**NOTE**:

During form population, i.e. `oef = OrderEntryForm(obj=oe)`, if WTForm tries to access obj.producetype, that will give you a `ndb.key`. As you can see, the first member of the oef.producetype.choices tuple is of `ndb.key.id()` as opposed to `ndb.key`

Comment: I think this is bordering on an XY Problem(http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Perhaps if I understood more about what you are actually trying to do I could give you a reasonable solution.

Comment: @nsfyn55 Is it clearer now?

Comment: `self.pt1.key` has to be a stringable value corresponding to the `<option>`'s `value` attribute. Is there some way to resolve `ndb.key.id()` to stringable value? If you don't know, but think it might be possible that would be an appropriate question to search/ask on the appengine tag. Otherwise you'll never be able to resolve a complex `ndb` key to the  primitive 'value` attribute of the form field.

Comment: @nsfyn55: ok I found out about formdata. Apparently I can populate using a namedtuple

Comment: `formdata` will coerce the wire format(a la `'1'` to `1`), but will it do it the other way around?

Comment: @nsfyn55 I did this in my test case and it worked.       `order_entry_form = OrderEntryForm(quantity=oe.quantity, producetype=oe.producetype.id())`