# Add input fields dynamically with wtforms

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I'm not quite sure how approach this matter. I hope i get there.

For example I have a table full of addresses on a page. The count of these are dynamic (could be 5 or 10 or any other count). And I want the possibility to edit them on one page.

My approach was to create a Form with wtforms to edit one address and to multiply
it in a jinja2 `for loop` and append to the html propertys `name` and `id` the 
`loop.index0` from the itereation, so i can extract each row of data manually
and put it back in my form, when I want to evaluate it.

So the Form for this example would be:

```
class AdressForm(Form):
    name = TextField()
```

so now my template aproach looks like the following (break down to one input field):

```
{% for address in addresses %}
    {{ forms.render_field(addressform.name, id = "name_" ~ loop.index0, 
                          name = "name_" ~ loop.index0, value = address.name) }}
{% endfor %}
```

(forms.render_field is just a macro to specify the right classes to the field function of wtforms. like they use in many tutorials)

So this is not working, since you can't pass the `name` parameter manually to the field function, since wtforms create the `name` html-paramter from the variblename of the intial Form.

So is there a way to add a prefix or postfix to the name of a form I want to render. 
Or is this a XY-Problem and my approach is totaly wrong.

or have I do it all plain by myself (I really try to avoid this)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

WTForms has a meta-field called [`FormField`](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/fields/#wtforms.fields.FormField) and another meta-field called [`FieldList`](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/fields/#wtforms.fields.FieldList).  These two combined together will get you what you want:

```
class AddressEntryForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField()

class AddressesForm(FlaskForm):
    """A form for one or more addresses"""
    addresses = FieldList(FormField(AddressEntryForm), min_entries=1)
```

To create entries in the AddressesForm, simply use a list of dictionaries:

```
user_addresses = [{"name": "First Address"},
                  {"name": "Second Address"}]
form = AddressesForm(addresses=user_addresses)
return render_template("edit.html", form=form)
```

Then, in your template, simply loop over the sub-forms:

```
{% from 'your_form_template.jinja' import forms %}
{% for address_entry_form in form.addresses %}
    {{ address_entry_form.hidden_tag() }}
    {# Flask-WTF needs `hidden_tag()` so CSRF works for each form #}
    {{ forms.render_field(address_entry_form.name) }}
{% endfor %}
```

WTForms will automatically prefix the names and the IDs correctly, so when you post the data back you will be able to just get `form.addresses.data` and get back a list of dictionaries with the updated data.

Comment: Thx, it's working. Only just not with a form element named `name`. With some try and error `address_entry_form.name` would always by the prefix of the fieldname/id

Comment: oh and with `type` the same problem

Comment: Is there a way to adapt this so that I could add Fields via the templates? I would like to allow a user to click a + button and have another field added to the FieldList.

Comment: Yes - simply have the click post back to your endpoint and when that particular post request is received just add another entry to your data list (in the example above, it's `user_addresses`).

Comment: But how do I do that without resetting all my form fields. To explain in simple  problem. If user selects radio button with number 1 or 2 or 3, the form seamlessly generates the new the correct number of form fields for the user without losing any previous form info. If I post back to my form view route in flask, it resets my form by does add the new field. I do the post through an ajax call to a special view route whose function is to redirect to the route with my form. In a sense I just want to rerender my form based in user actions from the front end.

Comment: @alexfvolk - ask a separate question - the margin is too narrow to contain an answer ;-)

Comment: @alexfvolk does your question answered somewhere ?

Comment: To work with CSRF tokens, be sure to add `hidden_tag()` to both forms.  So in this example, `{{ form.hidden_tag() }}` and `{{ address_entry_form.hidden_tag() }}` are needed.

Comment: Note that `Form` is deprecated (use `FlaskForm`). I also think the `render_field` method no longer works. Just call `address_entry_form.name` instead

Answer (score 6):

[Sean Vieira's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28378186/7781935) works great for `StringFields` (previously `TextField`), but things get a little trickier for dynamic `SelectFields`. For anyone interesting in how to implement dynamic `SelectFields` with `wtforms`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57548509/7781935