# Creating variable number of form fields in WTForms

Tags: flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

Currently I am trying to create a form where users can create flash cards, and there is not a set number of flash cards - you can add or remove them.

I have tried to use a `FieldList` of `FormFields`, where the `FormField` is a form for the flash card. However, I don't fully understand how this works (the docs aren't very helpful) and can't create a variable number of `FormFields`.

Additionally, I have tried looping through a `for` loop and on each iteration creating a new `FormField`, however with this I cannot seem to access each field's data individually (I only get the first field's data).

I would be grateful if someone could provide a fix for these approaches, or a new method.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that for each flash card there is a title and some content. The types of form fields that make most sense in this situation, are `TextField`'s and `TextAreaField`'s from WTForms. Since you are working with Flask-WTForms you need to inherit the base `Form` object.

```
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
from wtforms import TextField, TextAreaField

class FlashCard(Form):
  title = TextField('Card title:')
  content = TextAreaField('Card content:')
```

When you call this in a Flask view function:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
  my_form = FlashCard()
  if my_form.validate_on_submit:
     # save flash card data here.
  return render_template('index.html', my_form=my_form)
```

If I were you I would use a modal for the form. Bootstrap has a modal that is pretty easy to use (requires Javascript). The other option to re-direct to a form page when the user wants to add a flash card.

The main point is that you can use the same form instance for all the flash cards. Hope this helps.

If you really do need "dynamic form composition" it goes like this ([from WTForms doc's](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/specific_problems/#dynamic-form-composition)):

```
def my_view():
    class F(MyBaseForm):
        pass

    F.username = StringField('username')
    for name in iterate_some_model_dynamically():
        setattr(F, name, StringField(name.title()))

    form = F(request.POST, ...)
    # do view stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is quite old at this point, but in case it helps someone else: I believe `FieldList` and `FormField` are the proper solution here.

(I wasn't able to get the dynamic form composition from wgwz's answer to work.)

I'll use the example code that wgwz gave:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import TextField, TextAreaField

class FlashCardForm(FlaskForm):
  title = TextField('Card title:')
  content = TextAreaField('Card content:')
```

Now, I'll create a new form to hold all the flashcards:

```
class FlashCardSubmissionForm(FlaskForm):
  flashcards = FieldList(FormField(FlashCardForm), min_entries=1)
```

Then, I can use the new form in a route such as this:

```
@app.route('/submit/', methods=["POST"])
def submit_flashcards():
  # Here's an example of what your request data would look like:
  example_data = {"flashcards": [
    {title: "Andy Dwyer", content: "Loveable idiot; fell in a pit"},
    {title: "Bert Macklin", content: "Incredible FBI agent"}
  ]}
  form = FlashCardSubmissionForm()
  # I'm not sure why, but I needed to process the data like this
  # in order to populate the FieldList.
  form.process(data=example_data)
```

Since I'm not using Jinja to render my form, I can't speak to how you would do that, but this answer has an example you might be able to use: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28378186/3761310

I hope this helps someone else!