# Dynamically add new WTForms FieldList entries from user interface

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2, wtforms

I have a flask + wtforms app where I want users to be able to input both a parent object, and an arbitrary number of child objects. I'm not sure what the best way to dynamically create new child form input fields from the user interface.

### What I've got so far

Below is a complete working example. (Note: this is an artificial example to highlight all the working parts inside a single .py file, which makes for some pretty messy code. Sorry.)

```
from flask import Flask, render_template_string
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import FieldList, FormField, StringField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired


# Here I'm defining a parent form, AuthorForm, and a child form, BookForm.
# I'm using the FieldList and FormField features of WTForms to allow for multiple
# nested child forms (BookForms) to be attached to the parent (AuthorForm).
class BookForm(FlaskForm):
    title = StringField('title', validators=[InputRequired()])
    genre = StringField('genre', validators=[InputRequired()])

# I'm defining a min_entry of 1 so that new forms contain a blank BookForm entry
class AuthorForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField('name', validators=[InputRequired()])
    books = FieldList(FormField(BookForm), min_entries=1)
    submit = SubmitField('Save')


# Here's my Jinja template
html_template_string = """
<html>
    <head><title>stackoverflow example</title></head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post" role="form">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            {{ form.name.label }} {{ form.name() }}
            {% for book in form.books %}
                <p>
                {{ book.title.label }} {{ book.title() }}
                {{ book.genre.label }} {{ book.genre() }}
                {{ book.hidden_tag() }}
                </p>
            {% endfor %}
            {{ form.submit() }}
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
"""

# Alright, let's start the app and try out the forms
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret'

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = AuthorForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        for book in form.books.data:
            print(book)
    return render_template_string(html_template_string, form=form)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

### Where I get stuck

I know how to create new child entries (BookForm entries) on the server side. I could just pass empty dictionaries to my form, and WTForms would generate the inputs for me:

```
...
form = AuthorForm()
form.books.append_child({})
form.books.append_child({})
form.books.append_child({})
...
```

Bam, now my page has input fields for three books, and I could've prepopulated their data. 
WTForms is generating the form input content before the page is rendered. It works out all the ID's necessary for each input, etc.

If I want a user to be able to click a button and add new instances of BookForm inputs from the user side, after the page has been rendered … how do I go about it? Do I have to manually construct the input fields myself in JavaScript, using what was generated by WTForms as a reference? This seems messy and prone to breakage, or at least to ugly code.

Is there a way for WTForms to render the HTML for new inputs as needed, managing the uniqueness of input tag ID's and such? I could post something back to the server to append blank entries to the form and re-render the page, but that would lose me all of my existing user input, so it doesn't really work. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28375565/add-input-fields-dynamically-with-wtforms) Stackoverflow question suggests the same thing in the comments, and the same objection is raised.

If this has to be done the ugly manual way, then I can manage that. I just don't want to take a poor approach when there's a better (and maybe even official) solution to this.

Comment: This is basically what jquery was built to do.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54100606/5320906) does something like what is required.  Cloning the relevant field enclosures in js, incrementing the ids and rendering the 'new' markup is the only sensible way to do it I think.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I understand PERFECTLY what your question, to use pure Flask to achieve this. 
But I was at your same situation a couple of months back. And after a lot of research and odd and redundant methods, I found, implementing it will be not only painstaking, but long and hard and any small change or debugging efforts just breaks the whole thing.

I know this isnt exactly what you asked. But, if you are looking to do this through Flask+ jQuery. I'll show you some of the work I did to dynamically load data from HTML front-end via views, hope this can be helpful to you, IF you change your mind and decided to incorporate some jQuery.

This is my form, using HTML and Jinja2 :

```
<form method="POST" action="">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">XYZ</legend>

                <div>
                    {{ form.standard.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                    {{ form.standard(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                </div>

                <div>
                    {{ form.wps.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                    {{ form.wps(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                </div>
            ... 
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.submit(class='btn btn-outline-success') }}
            </div>

        </form>
```

This is the view this calls this form :

```
@app.route("/newqualification/<welder_id>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def newqualification(welder_id=None):
    form = #passformhere

        #writemethod.

    return render_template('xyz.html', title='xyz', form=form)
```

And this is the little helpful jQuery Script I wrote which you can include in the HTML via `<script>` tag.

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#standard").change(function(){
                var std = $(this).find('option:selected').val(); //capture value from form.

                $.getJSON("{{url_for('modifywps')}}",{'std':std}, function(result){ //use captured value to sent to view via a dictionary {'key':val}, via url_for('view_name')

                    $.each(result, function(i, field){ //value you want will be back here and gone through..
                        $.each(field, function(j,k){
                            $("#wps").append('<option value="'+j+'">'+k+'</option>'); // use jQuery to insert it back into the form, via the form name you gave in jinja templating
                        });
                    });
                });
            });


            $("#wps").change(function(){

                    var std = $('#wps').find('option:selected').val(); // capture value from form.
                    $.getJSON("{{url_for('modifyprocess')}}",{'std':std}, function(result)

                        $.each(result, function(i, field){
                            $.each(field, function(j,k){
                                $("#processes").append('<option value="'+j+'">'+k+'</option>');
                            });
                        });
                    });
            });
</script>
```

Using jQuery and the `getJSON()` method, i am able to send a request to this view :

```
@app.route("/modifywps", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def modifywps():
    application_standard_id = request.args.get('std') # gets value from the getJson()

   # process it however you want.. 

    return #whatever you want.
```

So every time there is a change, data is read dynamically off the site, sent to a Flask view, processed there with whatever you want, sent back the the same `getJSON()` and inserted right into the form!! 
Voila, you have dynamically used jQuery+Flask to manipulate whatever you want to do, using your new best friend, JSON.

After a lot of research, i found the simplest way to do what you want above, is through jQuery. 
Learn `getJSON()` and `post()` methods in jQuery, incorporate it into your HTML and you have your answer. 
And also `jsonify()` which i believe you can import in Python via `import json`.

Feed a list to `jsonify()` which you can use to return as the view in the same `getJSON()` you used to send the data.

Comment: I'm going to accept this as the best answer - @dustin-ingram if you agree you can award the bounty

Answer (score 6):

Sorry for reviving this question, but I wanted to point out that one can implement a similar strategy without using javascript. The idea is to pre-process the form data on submit and then reload the form with the processed data (using the built-in capabilities of wtforms to recreate a form from its data).

One way of doing it can be as follows. Add an extra input field to the form and define an `update_self` method:

```
class AuthorForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField('name', validators=[InputRequired()])
    books = FieldList(FormField(BookForm), min_entries=1)
    submit = SubmitField('Save')
    addline = SubmitField('Add new line')  # This is the new input

    def update_self(self):
        # read the data in the form
        read_form_data = self.data

        # modify the data as you see fit:
        updated_list = read_form_data['books']
        if read_form_data['addline']:
            updated_list.append({})
        read_form_data['books'] = updated_list

        # reload the form from the modified data
        self.__init__(formdata=None, **read_form_data)
        self.validate()  # the errors on validation are cancelled in the line above
```

Note: `formdata=None` is necessary to prevent the FlaskForm to automatically read the data in the form. If you omit it, the form will receive `formdata` when running the `.__init__` method and hence ignore your newly processed data.

In the template, display the new input:

```
{{ form.addline() }}
```

In the definition route, call the `update_self` method as first thing on submit:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = AuthorForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        form.update_self()  # This reloads the form with the processed data
        for book in form.books.data:
            print(book)

    return render_template_string(html_template_string, form=form)
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

```
class AuthorForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField('name', validators=[InputRequired()])

    # ADD THIS:
    add_book = SubmitField("Add Book")

    books = FieldList(FormField(BookForm), min_entries=1)
    submit = SubmitField('Save')

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = AuthorForm()

    # ADD THIS:
    if form.add_book.data:
      form.books.append_entry(None)
    elif form.validate_on_submit():
        for book in form.books.data:
            print(book)
    return render_template_string(html_template_string, form=form)

# ADD `add_book` BUTTON TO TEMPLATE:
html_template_string = """
<html>
    <head><title>stackoverflow example</title></head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post" role="form">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            {{ form.name.label }} {{ form.name() }}
            {{ form.add_book }}
            {% for book in form.books %}
                <p>
                {{ book.title.label }} {{ book.title() }}
                {{ book.genre.label }} {{ book.genre() }}
                {{ book.hidden_tag() }}
                </p>
            {% endfor %}
            {{ form.submit() }}
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
"""
```

Comment: This is clever. I guess you'd do the same thing for `delete_book` using `pop_entry()`. I will try it.