# Submit WTform with dynamically generated fields

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I have a form where users can dynamically add fields to it. While submitting this form, backend only sees the fields which backend generated

```
#forms.py

class ExpensesForm(FlaskForm):
    expense_name = StringField('Expense_Item', validators=[DataRequired()])
    cost = FloatField('Cost', validators=[DataRequired()])
    due_date = DateField('Due Date', format='%Y-%m-%d', validators=[DataRequired()], default=datetime.datetime.today().date())
    type = SelectField('Role', choices=[('mutual', 'Mutual'),
                                        ('personal#1', 'Personal #1'),
                                        ('personal#2', 'Personal #2')
                                        ])
```

I'm passing this form with 
`return render_template('index.html', form=form, ...)` from the `main.py` to `index.html`

All 4 fields are generated via;

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="main-form" enctype=multipart/form-data role="form" method="post" action="/">
        <input type="hidden" name="count" value="1"/>
        {{ form.csrf_token }}

        {{ form.expense_name(placeholder="Expense Name", id="expense_1", value="") }}
        {{ form.cost(placeholder="Cost", id="cost_1", class="cost", value="") }}
        {{ form.due_date(id="due_date_1") }}
        {{ form.type(placeholder="Type", id="type_1") }}
        <button id="b1" class="btn btn-info add-more" type="button">+</button>
        <small>Press + to add another set of fields.</small>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" type="submit">Post Expense</button>
    </form>
```

A JQuery snippet generates the same fields with different(unique) id's after each button press as a row of new fields after the last `#type_` id.

When I hit the submit button, the backend only receives the first row not the generated ones.

What am I missing here?

**UPDATE:**

```
# main.py
@main_blueprint.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    dates = []
    form = ExpensesForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(form.data)
        # prints the following even when the browser sends more than 1 set of data:
        # {'due_date': None, 'csrf_token': long_hash, 'expense_name': 'Electric', 'cost': 13.0, 'type': 'mutual'}
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            for n in range(len(form.expense_name.data)):
                if form.expense_name.raw_data[n] != '':
                    data = Expenses(form.expense_name.raw_data[n].title(),
                                    form.cost.raw_data[n],
                                    datetime.datetime.strptime(form.due_date.raw_data[n], '%Y-%m-%d').date(),
                                    form.type.raw_data[n].title(),
                                    )
                    print(data)
                    db.session.add(data)
                    db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('main.index'))
    expenses = db.session.query(Expenses).all()
    # expenses_schema = ExpensesSchema()
    # output = expenses_schema.dump(expenses).data

    output = []
    for i in expenses:
        output.append(i.__dict__)
    return render_template('index.html', form=form, expenses=output)
```

**UPDATE 2**

Since `form.data` is a dict I can't have the names matching with the new fields. But even if I give unique names to the added fields the backend only displays the initial form fields with `print(form.data)` but if I do;

```
    for k, v in request.form.items():
        print(k, v)
```

I get all the fields. Doesn't seem the right way to me. Any thoughts?

Comment: are you doing multi select by adding a new type ?

Comment: @snakecharmerb Browser sends all the data. but the backend is not getting them.

Comment: @VillageMonkey Not sure what you mean by "multi select by adding new type"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only have a single form result per form submission.  To be able to submit an arbitrary and unknown number of inputs, you need to restructure your form with the help of [WTForm's field enclosures](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/fields.html#field-enclosures).

**forms.py**

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import (
    FieldList, FormField, DateField FloatField, StringField, SelectField)
from wtforms import Form as NoCsrfForm


class ExpenseItem(NoCsrfForm):
    expense_name = StringField('Expense_Item', validators=[DataRequired()])
    cost = FloatField('Cost', validators=[DataRequired()])
    due_date = DateField('Due Date', format='%Y-%m-%d',
                                 validators=[DataRequired()],
                                 default=datetime.datetime.today().date())
    type = SelectField('Role', choices=[
        ('mutual', 'Mutual'),
        ('personal#1', 'Personal #1'),
        ('personal#2', 'Personal #2'),
    ])

class ExpensesForm(FlaskForm):
    """A collection of expense items."""
    items = FieldList(FormField(ExpenseItem), min_entries=1)
```

I'd strongly recommend that you preface all your field names with `expense`, not just `expense_name` for sanity's sake.

**index.html**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="main-form" enctype=multipart/form-data role="form" method="post" action="/">
    <input type="hidden" name="count" value="1"/>
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {% for expense_item in form.items %}
        {{ form.expense_name(placeholder="Expense Name", value="") }}
        {{ form.cost(placeholder="Cost", class="cost", value="") }}
        {{ form.due_date() }}
        {{ form.type(placeholder="Type") }}
    {% endfor %}

    <button id="b1" class="btn btn-info add-more" type="button">+</button>
    <small>Press + to add another set of fields.</small>
    <br>
    <hr>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" type="submit">Post Expense</button>
</form>
```

Note that the `id` attribute of the HTML input fields must follow a particular pattern.  So for every new expense item field which you add by clicking on the `+` button, you need to re-number the `id` attribute of its input fields.

**something.js**

Everything else was comparatively easy.  You now need to write a piece of .js which will re-index the `id` attributes of all the input fields every time a new expense item is added.  I accomplished this using the Zepto library for Javascript.  It wasn't fun, and my .js is terrible.  The best I can do here is just paste the whole thing and hope it'll be of service to you.  I know it's confusing, but I was added multiple *classes* to a *course*.  For you, you'll want *expense_item/expense_request* or whatever you go with:

```
// append class-box when new class link clicked
$("#new-class").click(function(event) {
    appendClassBox('#classes', {{ newclass|tojson|safe }});
    reindexNames('.class-box');
    return false;
})

// remove class box when its "remove" link is clicked
$(document).on('click', '#remove-class', function(){
    var $toremove = $(this).closest('.class-box');
    $toremove.remove();
    reindexNames('.class-box');
    return false;
})

// add a new class-box
function appendClassBox(container, content) {
    $(container).append(content);
    // raise last and hence newest class box
    raiseClassBox($(container).children().last())
    return false;
}

function isNormalInteger(str) {
    var n = ~~Number(str);
    return String(n) === str && n >= 0;
}

// re-index class-box names
function reindexNames(class_name) {
    var $oboxen = $(class_name);
    $oboxen.each(function(index) {
        // Get all the input fields in the class-box.
        var $labels = $oboxen.eq(index).find('label')
        var $inputs = $oboxen.eq(index).find(
            'input, select, textarea')
        // Update the index contained in the name attribute.
        $inputs.each(function(idx) {
            var $name = $inputs.eq(idx).attr('name').split('-');
            // If number in name, grab from number onwards.
            var $has_num = false
            for (var part in $name) {
                if (isNormalInteger($name[part])) {
                    $has_num = true
                    $name = $name.slice(part)
                    $name[0] = index
                    break
                }
            }
            // Re-index.
            if ($has_num == false) {
                $name.unshift(index)
            }
            var $prefix = 'questions'
            if (class_name == '.class-box') {
                $prefix = 'classes'
            }
            $name.unshift($prefix)
            if (idx > 0) {
                $labels.eq(idx - 1).attr('for', $name.join('-'));
            }
            $inputs.eq(idx).attr('id', $name.join('-'));
            $inputs.eq(idx).attr('name', $name.join('-'));
        })
    })
}
```

**views.py**

```
@main_blueprint.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = ExpensesForm()

    # Iterate over a collection of new expense items.
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        for item in form.items.data:
            print(item['expense_name'])
            print(item['cost'])
            print(item['due_date'])
            print(item['type'])
```

Comment: I'll try this as soon as possible. Looks like I'm going to need the 
'''class ExpensesForm(FlaskForm):
    """A collection of expense items."""
    items = FieldList(FormField(ExpenseItem), min_entries=1)''' 

part. and I think I'm going to have to add the other fields into this new class. I know I didn't paste the `.js` but I can assure you that all new fields gets a new/incremented `id` which follows a pattern. This looks promising. Thank you. note: I suck at naming things.

Comment: nwm, you passed the entire class into the new one not the fields.

Comment: Please accept the answer if you feel it helps - otherwise feel free to let me know if I can provide additional pointers :)