# WTForm FieldList of multiple SelectFields only sends the first one in request

Tags: python, rest, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I implemented WTForm's `FieldList` with `SelectField`'s to render multiple select choices based on data in a JSON file ([as stated in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57548509/7781935)). It displays the select choices fine, but when I try to pass all the values that the user selected via a `SubmitField()` form, the request only contains the value from the first one.

Question: **How can I access ALL the selected values from my multiple SelectFields from my route?**

Interesting Note:

- I did this same `FieldList` approach with multiple `StringFields` and get each of the values as expected in the request. (Why would this be different for `SelectFields`?)

**The multiple select fields:**
[image]

- Here `Ford`, `Associate`, and `Bucks` are the values from the select fields.

**The request response: (from `request.form`):**
[image]

- Notice how only `Ford` is shown. Why not also `Associate` and `Bucks`?
- Notice how all the text fields show up correctly

**My forms (`forms.py`):**

```
class SelectForm(FlaskForm):
    select = SelectField(choices=[]) #TODO testing without placeholder


class SelectFormList(FlaskForm):
    """A form that supports multiple select forms"""
    select_entries = FieldList(FormField(SelectForm))
```

**My template (`home.html`):**

```
<form id="metadata_home_fom" action="{{ url_for('save_metadata') }}" method="POST">

    {% for select_form in select_metadata_form_list.select_entries %}
        {{ select_form.hidden_tag() }}
        {{ select_form.select.label }}: {{ select_form.select }}
    {% endfor %}

    {% for text_form in text_metadata_form.text_fields %}
        {{ text_form.hidden_tag() }}
        {{ text_form.text }}
    {% endfor %}
</form>
```

**My view (`routes.py`):**

```
@app.route('/home', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def home():
    select_metadata_form_list = SelectFormList()
    select_metadata_form_list.select_entries = get_select_entries()

        context = {"text_metadata_form": text_metadata_form,
        "select_metadata_form_list": select_metadata_form_list}

    return render_template('configuration.html', **context)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I was creating my forms in a loop without overriding the form's 
`name`, so each of the `SelectFields` had the same name.

The quick fix was just appending a unique id to the name:

```py
        for k, v in select_dict.items():
            some_id = uuid.uuid1()
            select_entry = SelectForm()
            select_entry.select.name = f"select_entry-{some_id}" # each SelectForm() unique
            select_entry.select.label = k
            select_entry.select.choices = v
            all_select_items.append(select_entry)
```